# Recorrer un array para imprimir un dato en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

me mandan el siguiente arreglo y yo tengo que mostrar un dato en un archivo .blade pero desconosco como recorrer la etructura de este array, ¿Cual seria la forma correcta? He intentado mostrarlo en formato json pero solo me muestra una linea

como he intentado imprimir el array

```
{{print_r($empresa)}}
```

y también he intentado con

```
print_r(json_encode($empresa))
```

Formato del array:

```
Empresas {#1140
  #table: "empresas"
  +timestamps: false
  #dates: array:1 [
    0 => "fecha_registro"
  ]
  #fillable: array:27 [
    0 => "nombre"
    1 => "razon_social"
    2 => "cp"
    3 => "calle"
    4 => "colonia_id"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:1 [
    "id_admin_zona" => 1
  ]
  #original: array:1 [
    "id_admin_zona" => 1
  ]
  #casts: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo en leer y ayudar

Comment: Lo que muestras parece un objeto, no un array. Probaste acceder directamente al atributo? `{{ $empresa->nombre }}{{ $empresa->calle }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los vectores o matrices en Laravel son representados como una instancia de la clase *Collection*, dado eso puedes obtener sus valores con métodos como:

- `first`
- `latest`
- etc

Ahora depende de lo que tratas de obtener es lo que tengas que usar.

**Opción 1**

Si usas el método `get` entonces obtienes una colección que deberás iterar para mostrar sus valores (es decir estás recuperando varios renglones de registros de tu tabla generalmente representada por medio de un modelo):

```
@foreach($empresa as $registro)
    {{ $registro->columna1 }}
    {{ $registro->columna2 }}
@endforeach
```

**Opción 2*"

Por el contrario si usas métodos como:

- `findOrFail`
- `firstOrFail`

Obtienes por lo general un objeto (que pudiera estar representando un solo registro de tu tabla) que no necesita ser iterado y del cual puedes obtener sus valores de la sigueinte forma:

```
{{ $empresa->columna1 }}
{{ $empresa->columna2 }}
```

Tanto el uso de `print_r` en las vistas no es una opción viable ya que no están diseñados para ayudar en la iteración de valores y mostrarlos en una vista, si no para volcar datos cuya estructura es compleja y no tiene relación directa con alguno de los tipos de datos primitivos.

**Referencias**

- [Colecciones en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections)
- [Métodos para trabajar con colecciones](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas para recorrerlo es lo siguiente

```
//controller
$model = Costos::get(); 
return view('carpeta.vista', ['model' => $model]);
```

```
//view
@foreach ($model as $value)
    <p>nombre{{ $value->nombre }}</p>
    <p>Razón Social{{ $value->razon_social }}</p>
@endforeach
```